# How does Retrofit convert to objects?

Tags: java, android, json, retrofit

In their example (http://square.github.io/retrofit), the third code block appears to retrieve data in the type `List<Repo>`, but where does the conversion from a string to a JSON array to `List<Repo>` occur? I'm a bit lost as to how Retrofit works.

In trying to replicate this with my own REST api, (json -> `List<User>`)...

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Could not locate call adapter for java.util.List<com.keenant.app.User>.
```

Comment: You know that Retrofit is open source? Just check the code: https://github.com/square/retrofit The code snippets you see is just top level for an easy dive in to the usage of Retrofit. This is not meant to explain internal stuff

Comment: If you want a more specific answer, post the JSON and your `User` class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Behind the scenes, Retrofit uses [Gson](https://github.com/google/gson) to convert the JSON to domain objects. In your case, Gson can't deserialize your `User` object. You'll probably need to register a custom TypeAdapter so that Gson knows how to handle your `User` objects.